# Gensim LDAmodel error: NaN and all topics the same

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, gensim, lda

Been following the documentation [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) and as well as in this link: [Machine Learning Gensim Tutorial](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/) and I'm at a complete loss for why this is happening. After tokenizing and lemmatizing my sentences, I put the sentences through a phraser, created a Dictionary, and inserted all the right variables into the model. Here is a sampling of my code:

```
tokens =  [[euid, sent, gensim.parsing.preprocessing.preprocess_string(sent.lower(), filters=[strip_punctuation,
        strip_multiple_whitespaces, strip_numeric, remove_stopwords, strip_short, wordnet_stem])] for sent in sentences]
#these filters are all default gensim filters except for wordnet_stem, which uses a WordNetLemmatizer

 bigram = gensim.models.Phrases(bag_of_words)
bigram_mod = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(bigram)
```

Sample token list looks like this: `['beautiful', 'Manager', 'tree', 'caring', 'great_place']` (completely made-up list)

```
texts = [bigram_mod[t] for t in bag_of_words]
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
sent_wordfreq = [id2word.doc2bow(sent) for sent in texts]

lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=sent_wordfreq,
                                            id2word=id2word,
                                            num_topics=5,
                                            update_every=1,
                                            alpha='auto',
                                            per_word_topics=True)
```

Here are the topics I'm getting:

> [(0, 'nan*"discovered" + nan*"gained" + nan*"send" + ...
>   (1, 'nan*"discovered" + nan*"gained" + nan*"send" + ...
>   and this continues on 3 more times

So not only are all the topics the same, each's weight is nan. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Updated: if you're having this issue, upgrade your version of numpy (it's a numpy issue). For me, conda install numpy="1.14.5" worked.